# When running codelabs' sample code, returns 'Error: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, youtube-api

The sample code can be found [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-cardboard-viewer/index.html#2)

After following the steps in the tutorial to deploy the application, it fails to display search results from the youtube v3 api, giving the following error:

```
Error: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.
    at Request._callback (/home/<username>/cloud-cardboard-viewer/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:85:15)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/<username>/cloud-cardboard-viewer/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/<username>/cloud-cardboard-viewer/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/<username>/cloud-cardboard-viewer/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
```

I have cross checked that I have the api enabled in my cloud console, and console.logged my API_KEY, which I set as an env variable, to crosscheck that the application is getting the correct key.

I have also narrowed it down to this part of the application:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var youtube = google.youtube('v3');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/data.json', function (req, res, next) {
  youtube.search.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    type: 'video',
    q: 'google+cardboard+video+3d',
    auth: process.env.API_KEY
  }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.json(result);
  });
});

app.get('/search', function (req, res, next) {
  youtube.search.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    type: 'video',
    q: req.query.q
  }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return next(new Error('Search error!'));
    }
    res.json(result);
  });
});
```

Looking through the youtube api [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#response) for youtube.search.list, I do not see auth: as a valid parameter, yet it has been included in the list of parameters for a get /data.json request. This seems like an intentional mistake for those following the tutorial to figure out. So, for those who have done this before, please what parameter do I need to pass in place of auth: to fix my error?

Comment: Is the API key a personal one that you created?

Comment: Yes it is. When enabling the API I also created the API key

Answer (score 0):

Paying more attention at the point when I create my API, it says the key can be passed as a parameter.

[Use this key in your application by passing it with the key=API_KEY parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqmIh.png)

I also removed the auth parameter which originally came with the code.

```
app.get('/data.json', function (req, res, next) {
  youtube.search.list({
    maxResults: '25',
    part: 'snippet',
    type: 'video',
    q: 'google+cardboard+video+3d',
    key: process.env.API_KEY
  }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.json(result);
  });
});

app.get('/search', function (req, res, next) {
  youtube.search.list({
    maxResults: '25',
    part: 'snippet',
    type: 'video',
    q: req.query.q,
    key: process.env.API_KEY
  }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return next(new Error('Search error!'));
    }
    res.json(result);
  });
});
```